# Running multiple copies of Nodejs corrupting my object data

Tags: node.js

I have a service which holds a javascript object, lets say `obj`. Initially when the server starts, the object is empty. 
I receive pub sub messages. Each message has two attributes, the type of the message and the data. Based on the type of message, I modify the object.

For example, if I receive a message `msg-0` of type `start` and receive some data `abc-0`. I add the data to my main object and now my object `obj` becomes `{abc-0}`.

Similarly, if I receive another message `msg-1` of type `start` and receive some data `abc-1`. I add the data to my main object and now my object `obj` becomes `{abc-0, abc-1}`.

So imagine I receive 10 such messages then my object `obj` should look like `{abc-0, abc-1, abc-2, abc-3, abc-4, abc-5, abc-6, abc-7, abc-8, abc-9, abc-10}`,

If I were to run just a single copy of this program, then, everything works fine.

But when I run 3 copies of this program, what I end up with is different. It creates 3 different objects, and  each object holds `{abc-0, abc-1, abc-2, abc-3}`, `{abc-4, abc-5, abc-6}` and `{abc-7, abc-8, abc-9, abc-10}`.

I'm running 3 pods on kubernetes and this problem became evident. And, when I run just one pod, the problem goes away.

What could I be doing wrong? Is it some sort of a common error?

Comment: Can you share entire code for better context?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when running separate NodeJS instances, they are **separate**. They don't share memory. Objects declared in one are completely separate from the others. In order to get this working correctly, the processes need to communicate with each other. I'm not entirely familiar with Kubernetes, but I'm assuming a pod is the equivalent of a process on a Linux system. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if this is the case, then that will be the source of the issue.

I would approach this issue by requiring timestamps on each chunk of incoming data, then keep a complete copy of the object in each process. When a new chunk comes in, place it in the correct position based on its timestamp and alert all other processes of an update and optionally share the new chunk or the complete object.

If the different processes (pods) are running synchronously (one after each other) then you'll need to inform the next process of the object at that point in time, so it can continue building the object as time goes on.

**TL:DR** This issue comes from NodeJS processes not sharing memory. In order to fix this, if the processes run concurrently, keep a running log of the object in all instances and alert all others, should new information be received. If not, inform next process of object at the time of process instantiation.

Hope I understood the question correctly, let me know if not.

Comment: Kubernetes is responsible for managing linux like containers. So, each pod can be viewed as a container in linux terms. Cant the 3 processes share memory, or, if not, is there any library in your knowledge that can take care of this?

Comment: If a pod is a separate Kernel instance, then the fact that you can't is intentional